# Can you alter usb protocols in Linux?

Tags: linux, usb

I have been trying to find a way to have a micro controller communicate directly with a computer through usb without a uart to usb bridge and I thought I could do it by disabling the usb protocols for the USB port and using the port as a regular serial port. I was told, however, that you can’t turn the usb part off. I also heard, though, that Linux leaves a lot more of the inner workings of the operating system open to altering. Does Linux allow you to alter the usb protocols and turn a USB port into a regular serial port?

Comment: You need a special dongle (USB to serial) to do what you want. USB and serial ports are *very* different beasts. Only thing they have in common is that they ship data one bit at a time (i.e., serially).

Comment: What hardware does the mirco controller have?

Comment: It’s a pic16f84a. It has no usb module that I can see on its data sheet.

Comment: you are asking about how to turn an apple into an orange

Comment: Well, I thought since usb seems to be just a serial port (universal serial bus) with extra data packets for the handshake, data checking, and other stuff the only thing that I would need to do is add those extra bits to whatever data I was sending and turn off the time limit that usb protocol has for response to compensate for the slow clock speed of the micro controller. Or turn off all the extra requirements by having the computer treat the USB port as a serial port.

Comment: Some devices DO have a switch that allows them to repurpose the usb pins from USB to serial. That's a hardware feature, not something Linux can provide by itself. I don't know of any "large" device implementing a host usb controller (eg. desktop or laptop) being able to do that. Besides, it's pretty pointless -- a USB->serial adaptor is $1-$5.

Comment: @user11937382 PCIe and SATA are also "serial" protocols ;-)

Answer (score 3):

USB is not "just a serial port" in any sense that would match the old RS-232 serial port standard (also known as EIA/TIA-232). You cannot turn USB into RS-232 by "turning off extra requirements".

Unlike the classic RS-232 serial ports, USB uses differential signaling: actually a little (very little) like RS-485, although the signal levels and other electrical characteristics are very different.

RS-232 can use signal voltages of up to +/- 15 volts: USB uses <0.3V for logical low and 2.8-3.6 volts for logical high in USB 1 modes; in USB 2 high-speed mode the voltages are even smaller than that.

Even if TTL logic levels (0..5V) are used in RS-232, the USB transmitter will be unable to generate a RS-232 "space" (=higher-voltage state) signal reliably. The signal levels just don't match up between these standards: a USB transmitter's signal would be too faint for the RS-232 UART receiver, and the RS-232 output signal would overload the USB receiver.

You can't get around the incompatibility with a simple level converter circuit, either: instead of sending just one start bit, then one byte of data, and then one or two stop bits, the USB transceiver deals with packets. At the start of the packet, there must be a synchronization sequence (8 bits for USB 1; 32 bits for USB 2 high-speed transfers), then several bytes are transferred, and finally the end-of-packet signal that will not match either of the normal "logical low" or "logical high" states. All this can be implemented in hardware for efficiency, and since there is normally no reason to do anything different, there is probably no provisions to bypass it for "bit-banging" the actual data lines in direct software control.

Compare the signaling examples of [RS-232](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Rs232_oscilloscope_trace.svg/1280px-Rs232_oscilloscope_trace.svg.png) and [USB 1.1](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/USB_signal_example.svg/1920px-USB_signal_example.svg.png) in Wikipedia.

To summarize: no, the problem is that the differences between USB and RS-232 are too great at the actual hardware level.

Comment: How does the V-USB do it, then?

Comment: V-USB is a software-only implementation of low-speed USB 1.1 (= 1.5 Mbit/s) only. You can do something like that if you have a few raw GPIO pins you can control directly, but in modern PC USB ports you don't have that: there is a big chunk of silicon dedicated to USB and only USB in the way, known as the EHCI or XHCI USB controller. And the modern microcontroller's signal levels are probably a better match to USB signal levels, so with luck you might not need a level converter circuit. You'd still want to add some protection from plug/unplug transients though.

Comment: Although it seems there is a test mode in the EHCI controller spec at least, that allows direct access to port signal states. You might be able to use it to implement the equivalent of a RS-232 UART in software, and then you'd only need the signal converter circuit. Oh, and you might lose the use of any other regular USB devices connected to the same controller (mouse and keyboard!) while using the test mode. Would be an interesting hardware/software hack, but not very efficient.